# Safari randomly opens links in new tabs and the same tab with middle mouse button click

Tags: macos, browser, mouse, safari, tabs

I was using Apple Magic Trackpad for my Mac but recently I decided to try Razer Orochi V2 and I found that middle mouse button behaviour in Safari is strange. Sometimes it opens links in separate tabs and sometimes in the same tab. I know that I can open links in new tabs with cmd + left mouse button but I prefer to use scroll for this purpose.

Comment: Have you tested this on the same link over and over and got different results?

Comment: There are ways for pages to use JavaScript to prevent you from opening links in new tabs. Coyld it be that when you've seen that behavior, it's been a problem with the page/link, not the browser? Or can you reproduce the problem at will by repeatedly clicking the same link?